# Delete items from dataframe that don't match another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare two dataframes, one created from an excel sheet (`tempSheet`), and one created from a sql table (`testdf`). I want to end up with one of the dataframes to have anything that matched the other deleted. Then going to use `to_excel` to put it back into the excel sheet it came from.

I figured `tempSheet = tempSheet[tempSheet != testdf]` would work, but I get an error saying

`ValueError: Can only compared identically-labeled DataFrame objects`

I made sure the column names were the same for both. the data is just two columns, both are numbers.

So I guess I have two questions. Is there a way to make the above statement work? Or is there a better way to do this?

My dataframes look like this:

```
   Qty    Price     
0  1      1.30
1  6      2.70
2  8      0.20
3  10     3.90
4  9      11.25
5  15     1.89
6  26     2.67
7  200    7.65
...

   Qty    Price
0  1      1.30
1  10     3.90
2  15     1.89
3  16     0.98
4  2      10.52
5  66     9.87
6  9      13.42
7  43     27.65
...
```

I want to cut the first down to only the matches, so

```
    Qty    Price
0   1      1.30
1   10     3.90
2   15     1.89
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just (inner) merge:

```
In [11]: pd.merge(df, df1)
Out[11]:
   Qty  Price
0    1   1.30
1   10   3.90
2   15   1.89
```

Comment: I asked the wrong question. I want to delete the matches. (But otherwise, that works)